# I can't see any result with using thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, thymeleaf

I get error like this when I used thymeleaf as view engine.

Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sat Feb 13 15:57:19 EET 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

My MainCotroller is like :

```
   public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView homePage(){

        ModelAndView homepage=new ModelAndView("homepage");
        homepage.addObject("username","Ayberk");
        return homepage;
    }
  }
```

My homepage.html file is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!--/*@thymesVar id="username" type="String"*/-->
    <p th:text="${username}"></p>
    <br />
    <p>GoodBye</p>
</body>
</html>
```

My pom.xml file is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>newproject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>newproject</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

</project>
```

My idea is Intellij 2020 and I have read this problem is related with intellij version. But i have not seen any solution. Is there any solution for it? What can i do?

EDIT AFTER RUDI'S ANSWER BUT STILL SAME ERROR.

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String homePage(Model model){

    model.addAttribute("username" , "ayberk");

    return "src\\main\\resources\\templates\\homepage";
    //return "homepage";  also tried like this.

}
```

My ModelAndView packages is org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView

Comment: What directory are these files in? In particular where is the `homepage.html`?

Comment: src/main/resources/templates/homepage.html

Comment: Couple of things to check; Check the import statement for `ModelAndView`, it should be `org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView`. Try switching it to a plain `Model` and return your path as a string from your controller method instead.

Comment: I checked and made all you said but still same error.

Comment: I forget the "@Controller" annotation in MainControler. When I added that then problem is solved.